# recvfrom in UDP not getting anything

Tags: c++, windows, sockets

i'm trying to receive data on a UDP socket, but I cant find a way to receive anything.

I can see with wireshark that the data is actually coming to the computer, but recvfrom always timeout.

The involved code is pretty simple :

```
mUDPSocket = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP );
if( mUDPSocket == INVALID_SOCKET )
    return 1;

uint32_t aTimeout = 5000;
const int lResult = setsockopt( mUDPSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, ( char * )&aTimeout, sizeof( aTimeout ) );

if( SOCKET_ERROR == lResult )
    return 1;

struct sockaddr_in addr = {};
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl( INADDR_ANY ); //also tried with my local ip
addr.sin_port = htons( 48640 );

if( bind( mUDPSocket, ( const sockaddr * )&addr, sizeof( addr ) ) < 0 )
    return 1;
```

And later when trying to receive data

```
if(recvfrom( mUDPSocket, ( char * )aData, aSize, 0, NULL, 0 )<0) //function return -1
    std::cout << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl; //10060
```

Im trying to do something basic, so I guess im missing something simple.

Edit : the packet is sent several time by second and the timeout is 5second, so I should receive it before the real timeout

I've attached a screen of the wireshark capture[image]

Comment: you got `WSAETIMEDOUT`. you yourself set some timeout `aTimeout` on socket and it expired before you got any datagram

Comment: What is the actual value of `lResult` when `recvfrom()` exits?  How is `LAST_ERROR` being set? Please provide a [mcve], and the actual Wireshark capture (or a screenshot of it) showing the details of the datagram that `recvfrom()` is not receiving.  Just because a packet arrives on the machine does not guarantee it gets routed to an active socket.

Comment: It isn't valid to call `WSALastError()` *unless* there *was* am error. Was there?

Comment: Post edited for clarification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I can see the code as shown timing out is if either:

- the datagram is not arriving before `aTimeout` elapses (what is the actual value of `aTimeout`?)
- the datagram is not using IPv4
- the datagram is not being sent to an IP on the machine, or is not being sent to port 48640
- the datagram is being blocked, such as by a firewall.

Comment: It's indeed the firewall, but why is wireshark able to see the incoming data if the firewall blocks it? And why is windows firewall blocking data on a port im listening to? The same program is already communicating with the same device in TCP and UDP using other port. On this last port, im just trying to receive data, and windows firewall only blocks this data

Comment: For windows firewall : I had to delete the rule for my program, so windows pop up would appear again, so I could allow trafic.

Comment: @DavidLevy Wireshark captures at a lower level than where the firewall operates at, so it sees inbound packets first. And just because you open a port doesn't mean a firewall can't still block data on it, as it operates at a level between you and the hardware. Since UDP is connection-less, firewalls usually block inbound UDP packets to a port unless an outbound packet is sent from the same port first, or you tel the firewall to allow inbound traffic on the port